# Mono's DateTime Serialization

Tags: .net, datetime, mono, remoting

if you uses Mono Remoting on Linux, what's your work-around for DateTime marshalling incompatibility between Mono and .NET Remoting?

i'm using WinForms on Windows using .NET 2.0 runtime, using Remoting on Linux using Mono.  i cannot yet use Mono runtime on both ends as Mono's DataGridView isn't yet working.

[UPDATE]

i used Mono 1.9 when the question was posted.  i'm using Mono 2.4 now, its DateTime is now compatible with .NET.  kudos to Miguel de Icaza, his team and Novell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a bug with a test case.

Answer (score 2):

I think a much better solution would be refactoring the code, so instead of the (yet under-supported) remoting, use web services. XML serialization of most basic data types are IIRC fully supported; and in certain circumstances, fits the architecture much better (especially server-client architectures).